# How to check if there's a value (inside array) including a value that I set?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two datas.
What I want to do is to check

(1)each contents value starts with one of categories.class_cd

(2)each contents value's length is categories.class_cd + 2

```
const contents = [
    "010101",
    "010101",
    "010301",
    "0103",
    "01",
    "01",
    "01400201",
    "01400201",
    "010103",
    "0118"
]

const categories = [
    {
        "class_cd": "0101",
        "name": "A",
    },
    {
        "class_cd": "0103",
        "name": "B",
    },
    {
        "class_cd": "0107",
        "name": "C",
    },
    {
        "class_cd": "0109",
        "name": "D",
    },
    {
        "class_cd": "0112",
        "name": "E",
    },
    {
        "class_cd": "0117",
        "name": "F",
    },
]
```

I want to get another array datas like below.

```
const categoriesNew =[
    {
        "class_cd": "0101",
        "name": "A",
    },
    {
        "class_cd": "0103",
        "name": "B",
    },
]
```

How can I sort like this???
I tried to use filter or map but it didn't work well.

Comment: If you tried to use filter or map, it would help to see exactly what you tried.  Paste your code and its output.  This will help people to understand your thought processes, to provide a more contextual answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you can do something like this:

```
let res = categories.filter(category => {
    return contents.find(content => content.includes(category.class_cd) || parseInt(content) === parseInt(category.class_cd) + 2)
})
```

```js
const contents = [
    "010101",
    "010101",
    "010301",
    "0103",
    "01",
    "01",
    "01400201",
    "01400201",
    "010103",
    "0118"
]

const categories = [
    {
        "class_cd": "0101",
        "name": "A",
    },
    {
        "class_cd": "0103",
        "name": "B",
    },
    {
        "class_cd": "0107",
        "name": "C",
    },
    {
        "class_cd": "0109",
        "name": "D",
    },
    {
        "class_cd": "0112",
        "name": "E",
    },
    {
        "class_cd": "0117",
        "name": "F",
    },
]

let res = categories.filter(category => {
    return contents.find(content => content.includes(category.class_cd) || parseInt(content) === parseInt(category.class_cd) + 2)
  })

console.log(res)
```